# Robot Framework how to validate list from other list

Tags: robotframework

For this im want to Verify one of the element is visible inside of other element but based on Multiple list

```
CAR
TOYOTA
HONDA
MITSUBISHI
SUZUKI

COLOR
RED
GREEN
BLUE
YELLOW
```

Scenario is if we can run Loop but run the validation in loop also based on other list
When User click TOYOYA then it will verify if element RED is visible or not.

For example here user have 2 List
@{Car} Toyota   Honda    Mitsubishi   Suzuki
@{Color}   Red   Green   Blue   Yellow

i want to check if we click Car Toyota then check if the Red color in there or not
Im try to use IF IN

```
IF ${Car0} IN @{Car}
  Click Element ${Car}
  sleep  5s
  IF ${Color0}  IN @{Color}
       Check if element is Visible ${Color}
```

END

In the end there are error in it, anyone can give me concept and answer for this? Many thanks (PS: Im still learn Robotframework, forgive my beginner}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With IF condition you have to use small "in" operator and add quotes to variable

```
IF "${Car0}" in "@{Car}"
  Click Element ${Car}
  sleep  5s
  IF "${Color0}" in "@{Color}"
       Check if element is Visible ${Color}
```